# How to Sync Screenshots to Google Photos automatically?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, google-photos, oneplus-two, oxygenos

I would like to sync my screenshots to Google Photos.

OS: OxygenOS 3.1
Phone: OnePlus 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Google Photos > Albums > Click *Screenshots, Whats...* and click the cloud symbol with arrow.